# NestJS/Class-transformer @Type Discriminator object doesn't correctly validate data

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have a generic class as following:

```
import {IsArray, IsNotEmpty, IsString, ValidateNested} from "class-validator";
import {PatientInfoValidator} from "./businessInfo/PatientInfoValidator";
import {TypeValidator} from "./TypeValidator";
import {Type} from "class-transformer";

export class GenericValidator {
    @IsString()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    userId: string;

    @ValidateNested({each:true})
    @Type(() => TypeValidator)
    type: TypeValidator;
}
```

And two classes which inherit from this class

```
import {IsArray, IsNotEmpty, IsString, ValidateNested} from "class-validator";
import {PatientInfoValidator} from "./businessInfo/PatientInfoValidator";
import {Type} from "class-transformer";
import {BusinessInfoValidator} from "./BusinessInfoValidator";
import {GenericValidator} from "./GenericValidator";
import {TypeValidator} from "./TypeValidator";

export class BodyValidator extends GenericValidator {
    @IsString()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    userId: string;

    @ValidateNested({each:true})
    @Type(() => TypeValidator)
    type: TypeValidator;

    @ValidateNested({each:true})
    @Type(() => BusinessInfoValidator)
    businessInformation: BusinessInfoValidator;

    @IsArray()
    sheetLink: string[];

    validate: boolean;
}
```

And:

```
import {GenericValidator} from "./GenericValidator";
import {IsNotEmpty, IsString, ValidateNested} from "class-validator";
import {Type} from "class-transformer";
import {TypeValidator} from "./TypeValidator";

export class CaseTwoValidator extends GenericValidator {
    @IsString()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    userId: string;

    @ValidateNested({each:true})
    @Type(() => TypeValidator)
    type: TypeValidator;

    newKey: string;
}
```

These are used in the DTO for validation:

```
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import {ValidateNested} from "class-validator";
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { BodyValidator} from "../validators/BodyValidator";
import { GenericValidator} from "../validators/GenericValidator";
import { CaseTwoValidator} from "../validators/CaseTwoValidator";

export class CreateSheetsDto {
    @ApiProperty()
    @ValidateNested({ each: true })
    @Type(() => GenericValidator, {
        keepDiscriminatorProperty: true,
        discriminator: {
            property: "type.label",
            subTypes: [
                { value: BodyValidator, name: "Hors dissection et syndrome neurologique" },
                { value: CaseTwoValidator, name: "NewCase" }
            ]
        }
        })
    readonly body: BodyValidator | CaseTwoValidator;
}
```

I'm expecting the controller having this DTO as params to:
Reject as Bad request all request body which are not conform to BodyValidator or CaseTwoValidator format.

Current behavior: 
API requests are very permissive, and doesn't enforce nested checks.

I was wondering if I'm missing something obvious having spent 3hours on this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the exact same problem a while back and figured out that decorators are not applied for inherited classes. Decorators i.e. (`@IsString`) must be applied to the class directly so you unfortunately must redefine the fields in your parent classes to your child DTO's.

See the TypeScript documentation on this [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#method-decorators). Specifically this portion

> A method decorator cannot be used in a declaration file, on an overload

Comment: Thanks, I'll start there and see if it helps making the feature work